# how to trigger change with @input decorator angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component which has a `title` field. This field is passed to the child component using the `@input` decorator. In my child component i have added some logic to manipulate the `title` value before showing it in my HTML.

Because my logic is in `ngInit` hook of the child component, only the first time the `title` field is reflected correctly. Changes that happen from then onwards do not reflect. Now i know this is because `ngInit` is called once but how do i trigger a change from my parent to child telling it to recheck the value?

**EDIT Added code snippet**

Header (child) component

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() title: string | Array<any>;

titleType = 'string';
tabletTitle: string | Array<any>;


constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {

    if ( typeof this.title == 'object' ) {
        this.titleType = 'array';

        // For tablet - only send the last most array item
        this.tabletTitle = [this.title[this.title.length - 1]];     // Has to be in the form of array (to be consistent with other orange header data type)
    } else {
        // Title is string - same for tablet
        this.tabletTitle = this.title;
    }

    // Temporary to show filter button on catalog page
    if ( this.page == 'catalog' ) {
        this.showFilterButton = true;
    }
}
}
```

Header template

```
    <h1 *ngIf="titleType=='string'">{{title}}</h1>
    <h1 *ngIf="titleType=='array'">
        <ul class="header-breadcrumb">
            <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="title | keyValueObject">
                <li title="{{item.value['title']}}">
                    <a *ngIf="item.value['link']" [routerLink]="item.value['link']">{{item.value['title']}}</a>
                    <span *ngIf="!item.value['link']">{{item.value['title']}}</span>
                </li>
                <li *ngIf="!last" class="separator"></li>
            </template>
        </ul>
        <ul class="header-breadcrumb tablet">
            <li *ngFor="let item of tabletTitle | keyValueObject">
                <a *ngIf="item.value['link']" [routerLink]="item.value['link']">{{item.value['title']}}</a>
                <span *ngIf="!item.value['link']">{{item.value['title']}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </h1>
```

Parent component

```
if ( this.parentCatId ) {
    // Push Parent Category name in header title
    this.headerTitle.push({title: 'Parent'});
}

if ( this.subCatId ) {          
    // Push Sub Category name in header title
    this.headerTitle.push({title: 'Child'});
}
```

Parent component HTML

```
<app-header [title]="headerTitle"></app-header>
```

Comment: Provide some code snippet or create a plunker/ jsfiddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either make `@Input() title: string | Array<any>` a setter or use `ngOnChanges()` instead of `ngOnInit()`. `ngOnChanges()` is called every time an `@Input()` is updated.

```
@Input() set title(value: string | Array<any>) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
ngOnChanges() {

    if ( typeof this.title == 'object' ) {
        this.titleType = 'array';

        // For tablet - only send the last most array item
        this.tabletTitle = [this.title[this.title.length - 1]];     // Has to be in the form of array (to be consistent with other orange header data type)
    } else {
        // Title is string - same for tablet
        this.tabletTitle = this.title;
    }

    // Temporary to show filter button on catalog page
    if ( this.page == 'catalog' ) {
        this.showFilterButton = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Does setting the `@Input` as `set` have any performance impacts or both methods work the same way? :)

Comment: Not, having it as setter doesn't have any performance impact. The setter is just called once every time change detection recognized a change on the parents `headerTitle` property.

Comment: For some crazy reason my IDE (Sublime text 3) is not recognizing the `@Input set` syntax. Marks it in red :(

Comment: Sorry, no idea about TS with Sublime 3

Comment: Well i have used the `ngOnChanges` method and its detecting the changes. However for some bizarre reason its not re-rendering it in the View layer (DOM), any clues why that might be?

Comment: Angular doesn't like when the model is changed in `ngOnChanges()`. Sorry, I forgot about hat. In this case you should inject `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}` and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` at the end of `ngOnChanges()`

Comment: Not working even with `ChangeDetectorRef`. Isn't this a very common case where the data from parent component is pushed into child components which might be coming from Observables/Ajax calls etc ? :(

Comment: Yes, it's common and it usually works. Just when `ngOnChanges` itself changes the model, then `detectChanges()` should be called. If it works in `ngOnInit()` I don't see why it wouldn't work in `ngOnChanges()`. Do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Nope - i am not getting any errors in console nor CLI. I am using webpack with angular-cli if that makes it any different

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas. I can't find anything in your code that could cause this problem.

Comment: Both methods `set` and `NgOnChanges` are not working for me. In my console log i see the new data in my `NgOnChanges` method. I noticed that in the official docs its little different in `NgOnChanges` method: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker? The Plunker editor provides a Angular 2 TS final template with the "new ..." button in the toolbar. What difference did you notice in the docs?

Comment: In the official docs they are not using the `detectChanges()` method
`ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    let log: string[] = [];
    for (let propName in changes) {
      let changedProp = changes[propName];
      let from = JSON.stringify(changedProp.previousValue);
      let to =   JSON.stringify(changedProp.currentValue);
      log.push( `${propName} changed from ${from} to ${to}`);
    }
    this.changeLog.push(log.join(', '));
  }
`

Comment: let me try the plunker

Comment: You don't need to use the parameter (changes) and you don't need to use `detectChanges()` if you don't modify the model

Comment: It works just fine in the plunker ( http://plnkr.co/edit/tM2p4VAKMyWswfF9Je4q?p=preview ) even without the `NgOnChange` methods :( - In my case headerComponent belongs to another module which is shared. Perhaps that can be causing issues?

Comment: You can create modules in Plunker as well. Hard to tell for me why it's not working for you locally :-/

Comment: okay i have found the reason - not sure how to fix it though. I have a nested subscription. It works fine if the data is pushed in the first subscription. However if its pushed in the nested subscription its not reflected in the DOM. The first level subscription is for the router (where i have subscribed the `params`) and 2nd level subscription for the request it send for that route to the service (where data comes from API).

Comment: Can you please create a new question with your current code, if possible with a Plunker?

Comment: Making a plunker of my code is little hard because its too convoluted. Takes too much time to clean it up so that it can run independently. I have noticed that if i recreate my array in the nested subscription it starts to work again. That means for some reason pushing data into Array in nested subscriptions does not work. However if the array is re-initialised in the 2nd level subscription, Angular picks up the change. Probably something to do with JS shallow and deep object detection cases.